# Аналоги(оптимизация) запроса

Tags: postgresql

есть таблица -

table_a

| id | name | price |

и такой запрос -

```
(select id, name, price from table_a where to_tsvector('russian', name) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'винт') order by price asc limit 1)
union all
(select id, name, price from table_a where to_tsvector('russian', name) @@ plainto_tsquery('russian', 'гайка') order by price asc limit 1)
```

Собственно, ищет по fts наименования и отдает с наименьшей ценой. Каждое наименование в запросе.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eaa2b/24

Можно ли как то избавится от `union all`?
И как это все будет если объединений будет много?

Или проще просто делать по запросу а потом уже результат объединять например `php`?

Comment: Гайку с винтом можно в один tsquery поместить. В документации postgres вроде понятно изложено. to_tsquery('гайка | винт')

Comment: ну а если будет целое поисковое предложение? и тогда не понятно как выделить отдельно самую дешевую гайку и самый дешевый винт.

Comment: Тогда и ищите отдельно гайки, отдельно винты. Если это совершенно отличные друг от друга сущности, какой смысл пихать их в один запрос?

Comment: Есть мысль астрономического градуса безумия: сделать `JOIN` на набор `tsquery`, записанный через `VALUES` по предикату с `@@`, а уникальность обеспечить с помощью `DISTINCT ON` на эти `tsquery`. И если выставить порядок по цене, то будет выбрано по одной записи на каждый `tsquery` с минимальной ценой. Написать это на SQL не осмелюсь ._. И сильно подозреваю, что перед отдельными запросами это не выиграет.

Comment: остановлюсь на варианте с отдельными запросами. спс.

Comment: @Zippbl4 Думаю, реализуя всё это отдельными запросами и объединением на клиенте, Вы изрядно проиграете в производительности. Пока по сети туда, пока сюда... уж лучше `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @Akina Уверен, клиент не заметит потери производительности:)